# When do you use react-native-push-notification vs @react-native-community/push-notification-ios?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native-push-notification

I'm reading the installation instructions for [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and it indicates that for iOS, you use `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios`. It seems as though you have to add both of these modules separately. However, I don't understand which to use in my actual code. Do you use `var PushNotification = require("react-native-push-notification");` as it says in [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification), or do you use `import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";` from [@react-native-community/push-notification-ios](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have to have both packages in your `package.json` but you do not need to use `PushNotificationIOS` for anything other than a finish handler [as shown in the usage section here](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#usage).

Generally though, you would only need to use `var PushNotification = require("react-native-push-notification")` and call your handlers on that.